# Python iteration error - code in my BeautifulSoup script incorrect, but why?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

do = dir_with_original_files = 'C:\FOLDER'
dm = dir_with_modified_files = 'C:\NEW_FOLDER'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
    for f in files:
        print f.title()
        if f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
            continue
        original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
        mf = f.split('.')
        mf = ''.join(mf[:-1])+'_mod.'+mf[-1] # you can keep the same name 
                                             # if you omit the last two lines.
                                             # They are in separate directories
                                             # anyway. In that case, mf = f
        modified_file = os.path.join(dm, mf)
        with open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f, \
             open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())


            for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='Test'):
                for child in t.find_all("font"):
                    child.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2'))

            # This is where you create your new modified file.
            modi_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
```

I have some HTML of this form:

```html
<td class=Test"> 
   <a href="www.randomsite.com"> </a>
   <font>Text</font>
</td>
```

In my BS, I am trying to change this to:

```html
<td class=Test"> 
   <a href="www.randomsite.com"> </a>
   <font><h2>Text</h2></font>
</td>
```

Notice the addition of `<h2>` tags around the text in the font.

However, for each file, it seems to be creating two additional files, neither of which are marked up correctly/as I hoped. If for example, one of my files was `file1.html`, this code would create `file1_mod.html` and `file1_mod_mod.html`

What could be causing this? I've tried stepping through the file in PyCharm but am still relatively new to BS/Python so debugging is a painful process.

Comment: @Kevin Apologies, I write posts here as I am debugging and this usually helps me step through issues, I stepped past the issue in the title and have updated accordingly :)

Comment: Are you certain there are no `file1_mod.html` files in your *source directory*? Just to be clear, this is not a BeautifulSoup problem; it is entirely constrained to how you pick filenames.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, my question title was ambiguous, I know this is an issue on my side! :) There is a folder with this name, but not a file of this name.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce extra files. Add a few print statements to see what the code is doing, for example. You can comment out all the BeautifulSoup parts, this has nothing to do with your use of that library (it doesn't produce filenames).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it may be due to the nested loops, for some reason it is still creating two mod files...

Comment: Your loops look fine to me; the outer loop iterates over directories, the inner over files within each directory.